# popping ViewControllers from UIBarButton

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to pop from one viewController to the next and I'm having difficulty adding the new ViewController to the stack in my app delegate. Is there a way to not have to add the new ViewController to the app delegate's navController and just jump straight over from another view?

So basically what I'm asking is I have added a NEW button to a viewController's UITabButtonBar
and I'd like it so that one that button is clicked it moves to the NEW viewController.

Here's what the app Delegate looks like:

```
-(void)navigate{

  //HomeViewController *home=[[HomeViewController alloc]init];
    MoreViewController *more = [[MoreViewController alloc]init];
    InBoxViewController *inbox=[[InBoxViewController alloc]init];


    // Add the detail view controller to the stack, but keep the root view
    // controller.
    UIViewController *root = self.navigationController.topViewController;
    NSMutableArray *viewsArray = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

    self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;

    if ([root isKindOfClass:[MoreViewController class]]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hide" object:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:inbox animated:YES];
    }
    else if([root isKindOfClass:[HomeViewController class]]){
        [viewsArray addObject:more];
        [viewsArray addObject:inbox];
        [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewsArray animated:YES];
    }
    else if([root isKindOfClass:[InBoxViewController class]]){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"getMails" object:nil];
    }
    else if([root isKindOfClass:[MessageViewController class]]){

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else if([root isKindOfClass:[ReplyViewController class]]){
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:[viewsArray objectAtIndex:(viewsArray.count-3)] animated:YES];
    }
    else if([root isKindOfClass:[RegistrationViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[ChangePasswordViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[InfoViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[ContactUsViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[BuydealsViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[FindThingsActivityViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[FindThingsToDoViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[ActivityViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[AskMeMoreViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[MyDealsView class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[InviteNewPartnerViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[ContactsViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[AddYourOwnActivityViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[AddActivityViewController class]]||[root isKindOfClass:[MapViewController class]]){
        for (int p=0; p<viewsArray.count; p++) {
            if (p>1) {
                [viewsArray removeObjectAtIndex:p];
                p--;
            }
        }
        inbox.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
        [viewsArray addObject:more];
        [viewsArray addObject:inbox];
        [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewsArray animated:YES];

        [viewsArray removeObject:root];
        [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewsArray animated:YES];
    }

}
```

I'd like to add a new ViewController called "mapViewController" so that I can navigate to it from another. Any ideas?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `self.navigationController` in each of your viewControllers?

Comment: Yeah I figured out my problem. It's basically what you just said. thanks!